# Has anyone tried to migrate users from the CFD Online forums?

Tags: discussion, community

Has anyone tried to convert [CFD Online Forum](http://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/) users to the dark side?  I'm not a member there, but I used to visit occasionally when I wanted to learn more while I was in school.  Obviously I'm biased, but I much prefer the Stack Exchange format, and I think the growth of this community would be beneficial.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried it. I think it's a good idea.

Software-specific questions are encouraged if they'll be of interest to the general community (i.e., not too localized). Questions about numerical methods and parallel computing applied to CFD are definitely welcome. Questions about CFD physics are probably borderline; it depends on how much the question also has to do with numerics.

Stack Exchange isn't supposed to be a replacement for package-specific forums. If CFD Online Forum users were to come *en masse* and inundate us with lots of questions that are only about one specific software package, like [OpenFOAM](http://www.openfoam.com/) or [ANSYS Fluent](http://www.ansys.com/Products/Simulation+Technology/Fluid+Dynamics/ANSYS+Fluent), I'd object.